# 【C#】 Type型で指定した型に動的キャストするには

Tags: c#, unity3d

APIの通信部分を作成しており、
LitJsonを用いてシリアライズとデシリアライズしてデータ送受信しています。

UI側がデータを意識しなくても良いようにキャストする型と
送信データをobject型でもらい、シリアライズして送信し
受信データをデシリアライズしてUI側にコールバックで返しています。

LitJsonでデシリアライズする時に、LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObjectメソッドを
呼ぶ必要があり、<指定した型> の部分に送信元からもらった型を渡したいのですが
できずに悩んでおります。

string litjsonString = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToJson(送信データ);
↓
HTTPリクエスト
↓
HTTPレスポンス
↓
object data1 = LitJson.JsonMapper.ToObject<指定した型>(受信データ);

■LitJson内の定義

```
public static T ToObject<T>(string json);
```

■環境
Visual Studio 2013 Community
MonoなのでC#はおそらく3.0
.NetFrameWork2.0+3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ジェネリックメソッドを動的に呼び出す場合のアプローチとしては

- `Type`を引数にとる非ジェネリックな実装がないか探す。
- `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`を使用する。

の2つが考えられます。問題のライブラリで非ジェネリックな実装は公開されていないようなので、直球の方法としては以下のような流れになります。

```
// オーバーロードがあるためGetMethodsを使用して全メソッドを取得
var methods = typeof(JsonMapper).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

// 対象ジェネリックメソッド定義の抽出
var genMethod = methods.First(m => m.Name == "ToObject"
                                && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                                && m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(string));

// ジェネリックメソッド定義に型引数を渡して構築する
// TODO:実際の型を指定する
var constructed = genMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Hoge));

// メソッドを実行する
// 第一引数:実行対象のインスタンス…staticメソッドのためnull
// 第二引数:メソッドに渡す引数の配列(object[])
constructed.Invoke(null, new[] { json });
```

という流れになるかと思います。

またソースを確認すると`JsonMapper.ToString<T>(string)`の実装は

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader (json);
return (T) ReadValue (typeof (T), reader);
```

となっています。この`ReadValue(Type, JsonReader)`メソッドはオーバーロードが簡単に解決できるので直接呼び出せば、コードが多少スッキリします。

```
var method = typeof(JsonMapper).GetMethod(
                                    "ReadValue",
                                    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                    null,
                                    new [] { typeof(Type), typeof(JsonReader) },
                                    null);
method.Invoke(null, new object[] {typeof(Hoge), new JsonReader(json)});
```

さらに言えば、該当ライブラリはパブリックドメインのようですのでソースを改変して上記の`ReadValue`メソッドを呼び出せるようにするのが一番簡単な方法だと思います。

Comment: 頭が全然ついて行っておらず、var constructed = genMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Hoge));　の部分までは理解できました。　　　constructed.Invoke(null, new[] { json });　の部分は引数の意味がわかっていないので検索して調査しながら意味を理解します。
　　　　
動的に<T>に型を渡す方法がどうしてもわからず困っておりました。
この機会にリフレクションを少しでも理解したく思います。

Comment: @user3732298 `MethodInfo.Invoke(object, object[])`の引数は「メソッド実行対象のインスタンス(`static`なので`null`)」「メソッドに渡す引数(string[1]→object[1]に暗黙変換)」という意味になります。

Comment: MSDNのMethodBase.Invokeメソッドのページを見て理解できました。
第１引数は静的コンストラクタである場合はnullになり、第２引数は実際に渡す引数になるのですね、配列になっているという事は渡す引数が複数ある場合は配列に順にセットしておくのではと思ってます。